# Обьясните значение слова

Tags: значение-слов, жаргон

Уважаемые пользователи форума, помогите разобраться в вопросе. Очень важно ваше мнение именно как экспертов в филологии. Слово "падла" - является ли оно нецензурным, оскорбительным или провокационным? Обьясню, почему я задаю этот вопрос. Я геймер и у меня есть персонаж с таким ником в одной онлайн-игре, но руководство этой игры считает, что ник не подходит по одному из пунктов пользовательского соглашения. Поясню, почему именно я выбрала такой ник: персонаж, которым я играю в сравнении с другими намного меньше по визуальным размерам, но по силе может превосходить многих, т. е. маленькая падла, которая причиняет много вреда. Но это мое видение смысла этого слова. Хотелось бы узнать происхождение его, конечно, не то, что указано в Википедии, там я уже почитала. 
Заранее спасибо вам огромное за ответ.

Comment: Я очень всем благодарна за ответы!Очень мне помогли!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Леся Глебова, я начну не с самого вопроса. Вы не там ищете. Вы ничего не докажете администрации ресурса, подобных случаев я знаю десятки. У них свои, мало завязанные на собственно русский язык правила, которые они сами себе и написали. Если они сочли, что Ваш ник что-то такое нарушает, значит им так удобнее считать. Спорить бесполезно. Даже если чего-то докажете, будет введено новое правило, что такие-то слова (по списку) запрещены в никах. Типа парикмахер - потому, что хер сзади, а херувим - что спереди.

Собственно по вопросу. Отнесение табуированного или другого неподцензурного  слова к одной из категорий сталкивается с той трудностью, что сами эти категории можно толковать по-разному. Можно смело сказать, что это слово не относится к матерным (хотя часто приравнивается к ним без всяких на то, впрочем, лингвистических оснований), а все остальное зависит от сложившейся практики, менталитета, контекста.

Слово, как я понимаю, используется в качестве синонима или женского варианта к "подлец". Как вариант - синоним "падшей женщины", шлюхи.

Да, в известном контексте оно может оскорблять адресата, но как чей-то ник - вряд ли. Тем не менее, если администрация сочтет оскорбительным или провокационным само упоминание подлеца или шлюхи на ресурсе даже в виде ника, то придется и всем посетителям форума считать слово таковым.

К нецензурным тут вряд ли можно отнести, если понимать цензурность в классическом понимании как матерные и грубо бранные (которые привычно "запикивают"), но у администрации опять же может возникнуть своя точка зрения, с которой невозможно бороться.

*Не буду специально разбирать другие ответы, думаю понятно, что, с чисто практических представлений, я не согласен со всеми, кто точно знает, к какой группе это слово отнести. Их спор - ни о чём.*

Comment: *Слово, как я понимаю, используется в качестве синонима или женского варианта к "подлец".* Вот это сомнительно, если верить ссылке Серже, в которой говорится о том, что "падла" от "падали". "Подлец" вроде бы с этим не связан.

Comment: Ну ссылкам Сержа можно не верить сразу ))) Тут дело такое, что этимология жаргонных слов всегда гадательно, на все словари надо смотреть с известной долей скепсиса. Ну а я ориентировался на сложившееся значение падла<падлюка<подлюка<подлец. Тут, видимо, произошло смешение двух омофонов (подлюка и падлюка), изначально с разным значением. Впрочем, это совсем не критичный момент для моей мысли.

Comment: Все-таки не удержался. Я как-то сравнил, случайную выборку слов у Елистратова (это ссылка Сержа), Фимы Жиганца и еще одного автора известного (забыл, вот черт, посмотрю потом, он у меня бумажный). Так 50% слов - с разными значениями у них. Про этимологию даже вспоминать не хочу.

Comment: Вспомнил. Кучинский третий.

Comment: Возможно, вы и правы. Только, к сожалению, мне эти имена ничего не говорят. Я вообще почти никого не знаю из этой области.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы,вы мне очень помогли,поспорить с администрацией проекта получилось и даже успешно.

Answer (score 0):

Слово *падла,* очевидно, является бранным, то есть ругательным и/или оскорбительным.

Answer (score 0):

Слово [Падла](http://gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_9093) не относится к матерным словам, это жаргонное бранное слово. В словарях оно дается с помет. бран. груб. вульг. и означает: плохой, подлый человек. Т. е. оно является оскорбительным, но не матерным.

Оскорбления можно подразделить на 2 группы.

1 группа - эти слова являются оскорбительными, если используются в соответствующем контексте. Если из контекста видно, что цели оскорбить не было, данные слова оскорбительными не считаются. К ней относятся:

1) нарицательные названия животных, например: козел, баран, овца, петух.

2) слова, связанные с сексуальной ориентацией или сексуальной деятельностью (первое – пидор, гей, гомосек и т. п., второе – проститутка, миньетчица, шлюха, а так же глагол «сосать» (именно как сексуальное действие) и т. п.)

3) слова, попадающие под статью о мате

4) бранные слова, под статью о мате не попадающие, но имеющие ярко негативную окраску (тварь, урод, сволочь, скотина, ублюдок, падла, подонок, бастард, лох и т. п.)

5) выражения, в прямой форме указывающие на неполноценность собеседника.

Таким выражением может служить медицинский или иной термин, известный в обществе своей ярко выраженной негативной окраской (идиот, дебил, кретин, даун, имбицил и т. п.)

2 группа - слова, увеличивающие негатив и экспрессию.

К ней относятся прилагательные и иные эпитеты, придающие ярко выраженный негативный оттенок словам, не входящим в 1-ю группу. Например, названия видов животных, кроме вышеперечисленных, сами по себе не являются оскорбительными, но в сочетании с определенными эпитетами таковыми становятся – «свинья грязная», «шакал гребаный», «крыса вонючая» и т. д.

Comment: Серж, ваша ссылка не работает.

Comment: Все, исправил ссылку.

Comment: Я сделал прямую, так вроде лучше?

Comment: Да, Артем, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Слово, безусловно, бранное. В принципе, "нецензурное слово" - это непристойное, неприличное слово, которое в приличном обществе употреблять не принято. Однако, если Вам необходимо его использовать для создания атмосферы (как, например, в фильме "Место встречи изменить нельзя"), то оно вполне применимо (только без фанатизма).

Слово оскорбительное, взятое из воровского/криминального жаргона.

Из чего следует, что оно и провокационное. Во-первых, будучи высказанным в чей-то адрес, провоцирует агрессию (вербальную или физическую). Во-вторых, называя так себя, Вы бросаете окружающим вызов + относите себя к определённому слою общества.

Comment: Светлана, бранное еще не значит нецензурное! Дурак тоже бранное. Значит оно нецензурное?

Comment: Интересно, а какой вызов автор вопроса бросает окружающим?

Comment: В моем понимании, что много слов можно использовать как бранные. Например, серая мышь - животное,а если я назову этими словами человека,то это уже бранное выражение. Так и тут,я называю этим словом себя,не окружающих людей. Я согласна,что этим можно спровоцировать на обсуждение меня как подлого человека или падшей женщины, т.е. взять любое обозначение этого слова. Но в таком случае можно спровоцировать любым названием себя,к примеру,я назвалась Кошкой,любой мой недруг в игровом мире скажет,что я гажу в тапки или любое другое плохое действие,которые совершают кошки.

Answer (score 0):

Лингвисты должны оперировать категориями "обценный" (включая матерный), "грубый" и "жаргонный". Остальное - дело юристов. Падла - слово жаргонное, не более. Ну отчасти - грубое. Понятие "оскорбительное" и "провокационное" - это не тут обсуждать.